# How to run VBScript from Oracle SQL developer?

Tags: vbscript, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to call VBScript file (.vbs) or VB function from Oracle SQL developer? If possible, please specify how it has to be done. And can we use `xp_cmdshell` for this purpose?

Comment: I just tried the below code in oracle sql developer but it's not worked and its working fine with Ms SQL Management studio Express Edition.   We have to configure XP_CMDSHELL before executing the below code.                                                                            EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'CScript D:\CreatesTextfile.vbs